# QtCreator deploy different version library

Tags: c++, qt, boost, qt-creator

I created a project with QT Creator and wanted to run on the Linux remote device (Ubuntu). However, when I try to execute the file on the Remote Host, encounter `Cannot Open Shared Object File` error. Perhaps QT Creator has built with Lib Version currently opened the local machine (Boost Version 1.75.0) so when I run the executable file on the remote machine (installed Boost 1.65.1), failure.

my question?

**How to build up on the remote machine instead of builds on the local machine and upload, or can change the version (Boost Version) something in Cmakelist.txt. Config QT Creator Or any other idea?**

[image: error]

Info Local VM:

- QtCreator 4.14 (Base QT 5.15.2)
- Boost 1.75.0

Info Remote VM (Ubuntu):

- Boost 1.65.1

Notes: I can build and run the project with CMake and make manually on the remote machine. It will then use the right version on the remote machine BOOST 1.65.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the Boost 1.65 binaries on your remote VM. Something like:

```
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost 1.65 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
add_executable(MyProject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyProject Boost::system CURL::libcurl)
```

Cf.
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html

Right now your CMake script has no way to know what `boost_system` and `curl` refer to and where to get them from.

Comment: I think that find_package call will look for at least version 1.65, not specifically only 1.65.

Comment: That's the point: make the find_package() compatible with both VM setups.

Comment: That won't solve the OP's problem if they are still linking with Boost 1.75 and trying to run the executable on a system with Boost 1.65.

Comment: I doubt he installed both 1.75 and 1.65 on the remote VM. More likely, he copied binaries  from local to remote and expected it to be compatible.

Comment: Right, they copied binaries from the local machine, and is asking specifically how to compile (through Qt Creator) on the remote machine instead of local build+deploy. Your answer isn't answering the question.

Comment: right @rubenvb , i use Qt Creator and build+deploy, so source code building on boost 1.75 (local machine) then in remote VM only install boost 1.65. I think this is how QT Creator works, Build (ON LOCAL) -> Deploy (Upload Remote).

Comment: Oh my bad then, I thought you also built from source on your remote VM. Yeah, you won't be able to use Boost 1.65 as a dependency for an exe which expects Boost 1.75. If installing 1.65 in your local environment is an option, do it and add `EXACT` after 1.65 in the CMakeLists above and generate/deploy your exe target. Then pray there's not other dependency (and ABI compatibility) issues.